# How do I enable local modules when running a python script as a cron tab?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, cron

I just wrote a small python script that uses BeautifulSoup in order to extract some information from a website.

Everything runs fine whenever the script is run from the command line. However run as a crontab, the server returns me this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/ws/undwv/mindfactory.py", line 7, in 
>       from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>   ImportError: No module named bs4

Since I do not have any root access to the server, BeautifulSoup was installed at the user directory: $HOME/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

I suppose the cron tab does not look for modules in the user directory. Any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: Did you add the path to your crontab file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the folder to your python path at the beginning of your script with:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("$HOME/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
```

Change `$HOME` to the correct value.

Comment: almost correct. the path had to be put in quotes and the path had to be specified for the *.egg folder inside the site-packages folder. Works now :-)

Answer (score 0):

`~/.local` paths (populated by `pip install --user`) are available automatically i.e., it is enough if the cron job belongs to the corresponding user.

To configure arbitrary path, you could use `PYTHONPATH` envvar in the crontab. Do not corrupt `sys.path` inside your script.